# Issue installing Docker Desktop 4.17.0 on an Azure VM

Tags: wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am installing Docker Desktop 4.17.0 on an Azure Virtual Machine. As part of one of the prerequisites, I am setting up WSL2.

But it fails with the following error:

```
Installing: Ubuntu
Ubuntu has been installed.
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/enablevirtualization
Press any key to continue...
The installation process for distribution 'Ubuntu' failed with exit code: 1.
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/WSL_E_INSTALL_PROCESS_FAILED
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Following the link for enabling virtualization, there is a CmdLet
Set-VMProcessor -VMName  -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
which is not available on the VM where I am installing Docker. Is this CmdLet something that can be installed separately, or is this inherently an Administrative restriction during the VM provisioning process.

Comment: I get a similar `The installation process for distribution 'Ubuntu'.... Wsl/InstallDistro/WSL_E_INSTALL_PROCESS_FAILED` error when I try to install Ubuntu on my local `WSL2`. I feel it's an access restriction posed by IT.